# Setting HttpResponse.ContentEncoding to GZIP

Tags: c#, .net, iis, encoding

I have a small `IHttpModule` that's reading a `POST` request from another server and relaying it on.  The response from the remote server has the header

```
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

How do i specify this in the `HttpResponse` i'm returning to the caller?  `Content-Encoding` is defined as a text encoding type, so it's expecting a text encoding such as UTF8.

```
context.Response.ContentEncoding = ???;
```

Should i be ignoring this and manually setting the header?

Answer (score 0):

If you modifying response, then you should, decode and read the content, gzip retrieved value and add header in response.

```
//Code for gzip the content and add header
context.Response.Filter = new System.IO.Compression.GZipStream(
                context.Response.Filter, 
                System.IO.Compression.CompressionMode.Compress);
context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Encoding", "gzip");
```

If relaying the response without any change, then no need to do any thing.